# textfield focus triggers rebuilding of UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

when I set `Textfield` `autofocus:false` it doesn't refresh the page but when I tap on the TextField, the keyboard shows then the main page rebuilds which causes lag.

This has been a problem for almost a week now. I can find problems related to textfields rebuilding UI but the solution cannot be applied to mine.

**MAIN PAGE CONTAINS THIS FUNCTION WHEN A BUTTON IS CLICKED**

```
void addCommentModal() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: AddCommentModal(
            onPost: (String text) {
              // APIServices.commentPost(context, i.toString(), text);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**AddCommentModal**

```
class AddCommentModal extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> onPost;

  AddCommentModal({@required this.onPost});

  @override
  _AddCommentModalState createState() => _AddCommentModalState();
}

class _AddCommentModalState extends State<AddCommentModal> {

  final commentController = TextEditingController();
  bool _canPost = false;
  String defaultProfilePhoto = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    defaultProfilePhoto = Constants.userFirstName[0].toUpperCase();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    commentController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("PHOTO: ${Constants.userProfilePhoto}");
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  child: Constants.userProfilePhoto == null
                      ? Container(
                          color: Color(colorPrimary),
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text(
                            defaultProfilePhoto,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(colorText), fontSize: 20),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Image.network(
                          APIServices.httpDomain + Constants.userProfilePhoto,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )),
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10,
              ),
              child: TextField(
                controller: commentController,
                autofocus: true,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => widget.onPost(commentController.text),
                      icon: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.paperPlane,
                        size: 15,
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      )),
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  hintText: "Add a comment ...",
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: "Poppins", fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same issue, been trying for hours :

> if your screen depends on MediaQuery or at least having one widget
> depenig on MediaQuery, the keyboard popup changes the size of your
> screen, which triggers mediaQuery and causing rebuilds...in this case
> avoid using mediaQuery, Instead get your dimensions using (sizer
> package) https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

Replaced everything related to mediaQuery and now works fine.

Comment: Do you know how to get whether the keyboard is visible without MediaQuery? I normally use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0` but that cuases rebuilds

Comment: https://github.com/MisterJimson/flutter_keyboard_visibility

you can try this plugin

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by an unoptimized code on Flutter's SDK: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37878.

The fix was merged very recently and is on the "master" channel.

Consider switching to that channel, using `flutter channel master`.

Comment: will it also change my flutter version? I'm currently on the stable version v1.9.1+hotfix.4 : channel uknown : source uknown.

Comment: It will change your flutter version, yes. You'll switch to 1.10+

Comment: after `flutter channel master` my app won't run when I try to debug. I also did `flutter clean` first before debugging.

Comment: I guess I'll have to figure this out myself. going back to stable.

Comment: did you find any solution? I also facing the same issue. Like when I click the text field, the keyboard appears and it takes some time to focus the text field also when I close the keyboard i can see the Scaffold background color for more than 1 minute and it seems like lagging.